# 'ng-select' is not a known element

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, angular6

this is my code:
I want to add on my form https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select multi select for tags input.

components.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
   ]

})

export class ComponentsModule { }
```

my modaltest.component.html

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        <strong>Gusti:</strong>
                    </label>
               [ERROR] --->             <ng-select [items]="testitems" [hideSelected]="true" multiple="true" bindLabel="text1"></ng-select> 
   </div>
```

My error is: Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select' Why?????

Can you help me?
Thank's a lot!

Comment: Is modaltest.component declared in your ComponentsModule?

Comment: @GianlucaParis No...

Comment: In which module is the component?

Comment: You need to either import `NgSelectModule` into your root module (typically called `app.module.ts` in Angular CLI project) || import `NgSelectModule` into the specific module that your declare the `modaltest.component.ts`. I would recommend importing it into the root so the package is available to your entire application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the `ngselectmodule` inside your `page.module.ts`.

Answer (score 19):

You have to import the `NgSelectModule` in the module that declares your `ModalTestComponent`, or, if your `ComponentsModule` is a wrapper, you should import the module that declares `ModalTestComponent` in it; this way:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
// add this line 
import { ModuleThatDeclaresModalTest } from 'path/to/module'


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    // and this line 
    ModuleThatDeclaresModalTest 
   ]

})

export class ComponentsModule { }
```

---

As an alternative, as @Narm said, you can import `NgSelectModule` in your `AppModule`, so that all children modules can use it.

Comment: I am getting same error in angular 5 . tried keeping the dependencies in AppModule , it still does not work

Comment: I found the solution, this module has to be loaded in app-routing.module.ts if you are using angular routing.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you should execute following command:

```
npm install --save @ng-select/ng-select
```

For more details [see the official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select)

---

If you want to add your own module, you should use following pattern

```
import { YourModule } from 'path/to/your/module/without/@/symbol'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I found that the order import is important. So I change the order, try to move all import libraries to top, and move down app component to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue. And observed that, I have imported
`ngselectmodule` in my module.ts file, but I missed to import the component itself in module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @ng-select/ng-select@^8.0.0` for those who have angular 14 version.

Answer (score -1):

just check the version against your angular verson no.
for Angular 13 command is  npm install @ng-select/ng-select@v8.x.
It works, cheers.