# ‘ng-select’ is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to use the [select component](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) for angular, but after I followed the instruction to configure the module this error is throw.

**Error**

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'ng-select' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ng-select' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ng-select' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   [ERROR ->] `<ng-select placeholder="Select city"></ng-select>`

**How my app.module.ts is:**

```
...
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [...],
    imports: [..., NgSelectModule, FormsModule],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I tried to follow the solution for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51446591/7123439), which has the same error, but even if I do this I get this error. I also tried to import and add the `NgSelectModule` to my page module, but nothing changes. I even tried to add the module to `app-routing.module.ts` because I read someone mentioning that, but don't worked either.

**Additional information:**

```
Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.2
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
@angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0
Cordova CLI                   : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After simply restarting the development environment and recompiling everything again, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ng-Select only in AppModule? Cause if you will use it in another one, you should also declare NgSelectModule.

`imports: [NgSelectModule]`

Comment: As far as I know, importing in AppModule should work for all other pages of the app. Nevertheless, I tried to import `NgSelectModule` in the page's module (`page.module.ts`) I'm want to use, but the error remains.