# Importing @ng-select/ng-select in Storybook/angular

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm trying to use @ng-select/ng-select in the storybook but it fails (MatIconModule works as expected).

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

export default {
   title: 'shared/rating-stars',
   component: RatingStarsComponent,
   imports: [NgSelectModule, MatIconModule]
} as Meta;
```

The error message is standard: "core.js:14937 'ng-select' is not a known element: ..." so it looks like that NgSelectModule does not define components properly. So I wanted to take a look at the module but I found out that node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/lib/ng-select.module.d.ts almost empty (reinstallation of package do not help and I can reproduce it on both win/linux):

```
export declare class NgSelectModule {
}
```

Application itself is working correctly, any idea what could be wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446254/ng-select-is-not-a-known-element does this question helps you?

Comment: @Amer - yes, I have removed the package (rm -rf) and I have reinstall it. I have also tried it on both windows and linux system, so I know it is not a local misconfiguration.

Comment: @Simone I saw that post before but it did not help. I should (and will) mention it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may not require to import NgSelectModule in your component.
Instead import it in your parent module.ts like this. Then you can use it in your html file.

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    .....
    NgSelectModule,
    .....
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Comment: imho this is valid answer when used directly in the application but when storybook (or probably other test suite) is used then this is not a real option. Or is it? afaik app.module.ts is not used in such scenarios

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [decorators](https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/writing-stories/decorators#component-decorators) and tutorial for [composite component](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/composite-component/#:%7E:text=Next%2C%20create,the%20story%20file.). Need to add it as moduleMetadata to the component decorators.